# How to find out the cost of our Android App or project before developing?

Tags: android

Actually I have a Client-Server based application developed on vb.net/C#.net now i want to port or publish that client-server Application on Android. I knew the tools for making it useful for my Android device. And I have also make out some important point to find out the cost of that project, but i'm newbie so i can't understand how to give assign or fix a amount for particular task in android. My Points are:

1. Develop a jazzy look user Interface for displaying a data.
2. Check and use the Device's network connection state.
3. Use the web service for accessing the method/functionality of
   client-server application.
4. Also check and use the state of web service whether it is available
   or not and use the functionality or fetch the data on the basis of
   state.
5. Also the main thing is to maintain the server for storing the data
   and fetching the data via web service.

Any help is appreciated for finding and assigning the cost/price/amount to the Android application.

Answer (score 2):

This usually depends on the size of your target market. If you have a large target market, you can let the app go at a low price, because volume and economies of scale will kick in bringing your costs down while your revenues go up.

If you have a smaller target market, you're going to have to bump up the price of the application in order to recover costs of delivering to such a small market and move into the positive for profit loss.

For the most part, you can ignore the cost of developing your app. Development is mainly a one-time fixed cost that disappears over time. There will be some maintenance of the application itself that will cost money over time, but it isn't enough to worry about. Your server maintenance will be the brunt of your costs, but provided you're able to outsource most of the storage and bandwidth onto Amazon's extremely cheap pay as you go servers, you're running costs will be relatively low as well.

The greatest majority of your budget will be spent on marketing (depending on the type of app you are developing). Should you get a shoe in with the press, or market through ads on mobile, Facebook and the like. This is where most of your money will be going. Make sure to offset the cost of conversion with the revenue generated by conversion.

If you gave me more details, I could get more specific and help you out some more, but with what I have to go on, I have to stay broad. I wish you the best of luck with your venture.

Comment: Like what kind of detail you are asking for? could you plz tell me? Actually The app on which i'm working is a private app which is used by the company's itself and no that app doesn't relate with any kind of ad or social networking sites. The purpose of developing the app is to make the work easy.

Comment: Ah I see. Are you developing the app for a company or are you looking to develop it for your own company?

Comment: I'm looking to develop it for my own

Comment: You're running costs will be very low. It will be virtually nothing if you already have your own server. The cost of development will range in the thousands, but that would be the one time fixed cost. If you don't have your own server, make sure the developers you hire delegate most of the server usage to Amazon's servers.

Comment: how much it will be if I develop it for my own or for other company? Be specific plz!

Comment: It should be around the same for either one. The only varying factor is whether or not you or the other company already has a server set up. Already having a server drops around a thousand dollars off the cost of development and shortens the turnaround time considerably.

Comment: We have a server set up with us

Comment: Are you looking for an exact quote?

Comment: Now what is the cost of that project?

Comment: Anyway Thanks for your time I think this conversation will help me in future add the price with my apps...                                             Thanks a ton again!